# SV: How to create functional coverage for transitions without having to worry about clock cycles?

Tags: functional-testing, system-verilog, function-coverage

Normally, I would just use repetition method for a lengthy sequence of time for a certain transition.

ie.

```
  covergroup test1 @(posedge clk)
  coverpoint( signal[1], signal[0]) 
 {
  bins transition1 = (2'b00[*1:100] =>2'b11[*1:100] => 2'b00) 
 }
```

Is there another method to check for multiple transitions but not have a set limit for repetition. To clarify I want to be able to check if certain transitions happen, but not care about the time( clk cycles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't define a sampling event for the covergroup i.e. no `@(posedge clk)`
define the coverpoint without [*1:100] and sample using `covergroup_name.sample()`